# onClick="window.location -- trying to change to open link in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, window.open, window.location

Just trying to make this current code open the link in a **new tab**. Tried fixes found on this site for similar problems but haven't been able to get it working yet...

Current working code is:

```
<div onClick="window.location='https://URL';" class="element _element element-4"></div>
```

From researching, I've heard I should change it to onClick=window.open so I've changed this now to:

```
<div onClick=window.open(https://URL, Name) class="element _element element-4"></div>
```

**Problem is**, when I do change the code to window.open (as per above) clicking the link doesn't do anything at all now, let alone open in a new tab.

Is it something to do with /div? Do I need to alter the CSS or JS? Any help greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: whats wrong with using `<a href="http://..." target="_blank">Link</a>` ??

Answer (score 11):

I guess that you've called the function in a wrong formula. Please check your function's parameters.

You can see more details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

e.g. that works: `onClick="window.open('yourURL');"`

Answer (score 4):

You need to be passing in the `url` and `name` as strings:

```
window.open("https://amazon.com", "amz");
```

see if the helps.

However, users can change settings on some browser to affect the way opening a new window or clicking on a link behaves (see `target` attribute in [reference for links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes)). So, you may not always get the desired result depending on the user's settings and browser choice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I've changed to 

'code' <div onClick=window.open('URL';, '_blank') class="element _element element-4"></div> 

But unfortunately the link still doesn't do anything at all upon being clicked on.

Comment: Can you post your actual code to look at?  The 'URL' isn't a url but a static string.  And the `_blank` doesn't go there as the window name argument but should be in a target attribute on the A tag itself

Comment: For anyone confused. The name attribute *is* the `target` - window.open("http://yourlink.com", "_self");

Comment: The second argument in `window.open()` is adding a window.name, which you can see is being changed in case of `amazon.com`, as soon as the page loads, you can check in console the result of `window.name` is not the same as you set. Other websites behave normally.

Answer (score 2):

```
<span 
   class="pseudolink" 
   onclick="location='https://jsfiddle.net/'">
Go TO URL
</span>

.pseudolink { 
   color:blue; 
   text-decoration:underline; 
   cursor:pointer; 
   }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mafais/bys46d5w/

Answer (score 0):

As Pedro Estrada said in their comment, the reasonable way to solve this is with a real link:

```
<a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank"></a>
```

If you need the block layout of a `<div>`, style the link with `display: block`.

Real links have a number of useful features that fake JS hacks lack:

- They can be opened in a new tab or new window, as the user desires
- You can see where the link points before opening it
- You can copy the link (or any other feature in the browser right-click menu)
- Screen readers treat `<a>`s as links. Trying to copy this with JS will be fragile and buggy.
- If your JS fails to load or your user doesn't have JS enabled, the link still works
- Your website is faster to load and faster to run because it doesn't rely on JavaScript to poorly ape a feature that the browser has already implemented